# parent-child and child-parent relationships in one query SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql

Is it possible to write a query to access parent-child and child-parent objects, in one SOQL query?
I have a scenario where, I need to access Account Objects from child and child of Account too, in the same query.
Example:

```
Select Id,
(Select Id,Name, (Select Id, Address from Addresses__r) from x__r.Account),
x__r.Account.Name
From x
```

.
(Pardon me, if I use any wrong terms. I am pretty new to Salesforce)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so.

In the example below, we are using sub-query to retrieve Ids of all Account Territories (parent-to-child relationship) and, at the same time, we are using child-to-parent relationship to retrieve TimeZoneSidKey of the User who has created the record.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Accounts_Territories__r), CreatedBy.TimeZoneSidKey FROM Account
```

[Documentation on the topic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding)